# Nonconservation of hypercharge in Higgs decay

Tags: standard-model, higgs, electroweak, isospin-symmetry

From Wikipedia, Higgs boson has hypercharge of +1 and isospin of -1/2.

W bosons have hypercharge 0 and isospin +-1.

Now Higgs boson can decay into 2 W bosons of opposite electric charge. No matter how hard I try, the quantum numbers don't add up.

Is hypercharge and isospin not conserved in Higgs decays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is hypercharge and isospin not conserved in Higgs decays?

Indeed, they are not. Both weak hypercharge and isospin are spontaneously broken in the SM, so they are not good symmetries: the SM vacuum "ate" some of them.

A detailed technical way to "see" this is by writing down the original term in the SM Lagrangian that gave rise to the trilinear vertex describing your decay, *g²vHWW*. It, along with the mass term for the Ws, *g²v²WW*, came out of the original, symmetric quadrilinear term in the covariant completion of the $\phi$ kinetic terms,
$$
g^2\phi^\dagger \tau^-\tau^+ \phi W^{+~\mu}W^{-}_\mu.
$$

Upon symmetry breaking, in unitary gauge,
$$
\phi \propto \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ v+H  \end{pmatrix},
$$
so the term $O(v^2)$ represents the W mass term, while the  $O(v)$ one represents the isospin and hypercharge-violation of the Higgs decay.

But note the electric charge is unbroken, and the iso-breaking matches/cancels the hyper charge braking, so charge is still a good symmetry, and thus conserved. Phew...